# creating http request URL which can be pasted in browser from server and request body json

Tags: python, url

I have the following three parts: server, json_str, req

```
server = 'http://example.com:9013/run'
json_str = '[{"Leg":[{"currency":"INR","Type":"NA"}],"P":"xyz","code":"0100"}]'
import json as js
    req = js.dumps({
           "func": "rfqfunc",
           "args": ["dummyQuote", json_str, 'True']
          })
```

I usually call to get a response for this using

```
request.post(server, data=req)
```

but using these parts How do I make a browser addressbar pastable URL like the following (which is the desired outcome):

```
http://example.com:9013/run?func=rfqfunc&dummyQuote&[%20{%20"P":%20"xyz",%20"code":%20"0100",%20"Leg":%20[%20{%20"currency":%20"INR",%20"Type":%20"NA"%20}%20]}%20]
```

I have searched a lot on urlparse, urljoin, urlencode but nothings has given me anything near to desired results.

Comment: could you share the desired outcome below the current outcome?

Comment: The desired outcome is the following URL only which can be pasted in browser: 

http://example.com:9013/run?func=rfqfunc&dummyQuote&[%20{%20"P":%20"xyz",%20"code":%20"0100",%20"Leg":%20[%20{%20"currency":%20"INR",%20"Type":%20"NA"%20}%20]}%20]

Comment: If you're sending data as a "post", then the data is not embedded in the URL.  It is sent in the body of the HTTP request.  Do you have evidence that the string works when pasted into a browser?  And your URL has a whole bunch of useless spaces ("%20") which did not come from the code you have above.

Comment: The code I have used is json.dumps(), which just makes the equivalent JSON string doesn't add %20 spaces. I have tested the final URL in the browser if we use the actual server address. it returns a proper response.